# JavaScript Validation for dynamic checkbox list

Tags: javascript, html, validation

I'm having some issues getting my validation to work. I essentially need to make sure that all textbox's are populated and at least 1 checkbox is ticked. The text fields are easy enough, but the way the checkbox's are populated is making it hard. Here is a snippet what my form looks like, there are a lot more after this. I can change the event on the checkbox's or remove them?

```
<form id="orderForm" action="#" method="get" onsubmit="return cdSubmitValidate();">
    <section id="selectCD">
        <h2>Select CDs</h2>
<div class='item'>
        <span class='CDTitle'>A Biography of the Rev. Absalom Dawe</span>
        <span class='CDYear'>2001</span>
        <span class='catDesc'>Comedy</span>
        <span class='CDPrice'>11.70</span>
        <span class='chosen'><input type='checkbox' name='CD[]' value='651' title='11.70' onclick='checkBoxCheck(this)'/></span>
    </div>
<div class='item'>
        <span class='CDTitle'>A Bronx Tale Soundtrack</span>
        <span class='CDYear'>2000</span>
        <span class='catDesc'>Death Metal</span>
        <span class='CDPrice'>7.80</span>
        <span class='chosen'><input type='checkbox' name='CD[]' value='652' title='7.80' onclick='checkBoxCheck(this)'/></span>
    </div>
<div class='item'>
        <span class='CDTitle'>A Little Deeper</span>
        <span class='CDYear'>2000</span>
        <span class='catDesc'>Rap/R&B</span>
        <span class='CDPrice'>8.30</span>
        <span class='chosen'><input type='checkbox' name='CD[]' value='653' title='8.30' onclick='checkBoxCheck(this)'/></span>
    </div>

        <div id="retCustDetails" class="custDetails">
            Forename <input type="text" name="forename" id="forename" />
            Surname <input type="text" name="surname" id="surname" />
        </div>
<p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Order now!" id="sub1"/></p>
```

Tried this so far to no avail.

```
function cdSubmitValidate(){
  var forename = document.getElementById('forename').value;
  var surname = document.getElementById('surname').value;
  var checkboxTicked;

  function checkBoxCheck(elemName){

    if (elemName.checked == true) {
    checkboxTicked = true;
    }else if (elemName.checked == false) {
    checkboxTicked = false;
    }
  };

  if (!forename || !surname || checkboxTicked) {
    alert("Input criteria not met. Please Review and try again");
    return false;
  }

};
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will fix it, first moved `checkBoxCheck()` function out of `cdSubmitValidate()` function, also the `checkboxTicked`. I think the problem was callign a function inside a fuction the console logged:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: checkBoxCheck is not defined.

Also in your `if` statement the condition was

```
if (!forename || !surname || checkboxTicked)
```

I changed it into `if (!forename || !surname || !checkboxTicked)`

[**CodePen**](http://codepen.io/Mi_Creativity/pen/RrpVWr)

```js
var checkboxTicked;

function cdSubmitValidate() {
  var forename = document.getElementById('forename').value,
    surname = document.getElementById('surname').value;

  if (!forename || !surname || !checkboxTicked) {
    alert("Input criteria not met. Please Review and try again");
    return false;
  }

};

function checkBoxCheck(elemName) {

  if (elemName.checked == true) {
    checkboxTicked = true;
  } else if (elemName.checked == false) {
    checkboxTicked = false;
  }
};
```

```html
<form id="orderForm" action="#" method="get" onsubmit="return cdSubmitValidate();">
    <section id="selectCD">
        <h2>Select CDs</h2>
<div class='item'>
        <span class='CDTitle'>A Biography of the Rev. Absalom Dawe</span>
        <span class='CDYear'>2001</span>
        <span class='catDesc'>Comedy</span>
        <span class='CDPrice'>11.70</span>
        <span class='chosen'><input type='checkbox' class="chkbx" name='CD[]' value='651' title='11.70' onclick='checkBoxCheck(this)'/></span>
    </div>
<div class='item'>
        <span class='CDTitle'>A Bronx Tale Soundtrack</span>
        <span class='CDYear'>2000</span>
        <span class='catDesc'>Death Metal</span>
        <span class='CDPrice'>7.80</span>
        <span class='chosen'><input type='checkbox' class="chkbx" name='CD[]' value='652' title='7.80' onclick='checkBoxCheck(this)'/></span>
    </div>
<div class='item'>
        <span class='CDTitle'>A Little Deeper</span>
        <span class='CDYear'>2000</span>
        <span class='catDesc'>Rap/R&B</span>
        <span class='CDPrice'>8.30</span>
        <span class='chosen'><input type='checkbox' class="chkbx" name='CD[]' value='653' title='8.30' onclick='checkBoxCheck(this)'/></span>
    </div>

        <div id="retCustDetails" class="custDetails">
            Forename <input type="text" name="forename" id="forename" />
            Surname <input type="text" name="surname" id="surname" />
        </div>
<p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Order now!" id="sub1"/></p>
```

Comment: See that was my through as well and I tried it and it didnt work. The only thing different was I wrapped the entire thing in a overall function to make it tidier. I don't really want a floating variable around. This doesnt work however, is there anyway around this?